ee.Geometry.toGeoJSONString() generate invalid GeoJSON
I tried to convert Google Earth Engine (ee)'s geometry to GeoJSON with following code.
import ee
aoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([117, 12, 118, 14])
aoi.toGeoJSONString()

The toGeoJSONString() returns following string.
'{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[117, 14], [117, 12], [118, 12], [118, 14]]], "evenOdd": true}'

I think it is an invalid GeoJSON in the following two respects.

The polygon is not closed.
An extra key "evenOdd" exists.

Is there a way to generate the GeoJSON which follows rfc7946 by ee?

I personnaly never used this method.
To get a well defined geojson representation of a geometry/feature/featurecollection, I always use the getInfo() method.
In your example:
import ee
aoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([117, 12, 118, 14])
aoi.getInfo()

returns the following:
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[117, 12], [118, 12], [118, 14], [117, 14], [117, 12]]]}

